# Receive Notifications from Child ViewModels

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I might be missing something simple, so bear with me.
I have a ViewModel that contains the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection
{
    get { return personCollection; }
    set
    {
        if (personCollection != value)
        {
            personCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PersonCollection");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in another ViewModel I have:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection
{
    get
    {
        PersonViewModel vm = (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).PersonViewModel;
        return vm.PersonCollection;
    }
}

public PersonViewModel PersonViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return ((App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).PersonViewModel)
    }
}
```

In my XAML if I bind to `PersonCollection` then updates don't happen on my view, but if I bind to `PersonViewModel.PersonCollection` it does. so is this the "proper" way to do it or is there a way for the view to detect the notifications using the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your binding to `{Binding PersonViewModel.PersonCollection}`

Your wrapped `PersonCollection` property has no change notifications, so the view doesn't know that the property has changed (it certainly has no way of knowing it originally came from `PersonViewModel` in order to get change notifications from *it*)

Comment: Ahh I understand what you are saying. I guess that's quite obvious when you think about it. So the way to use entities within a ViewModel is to give a property of the child ViewModel within the parent as per my 2nd way of doing it and then you can bind through that?